# Optimizing custom JPEG decompression

Tags: c++, performance, image

The aim of my code is to decode an image format that is based on the JPEG chain of compression/decompression, however it is not compatible with the default JPEG flow as far as I know, since all libraries I have tried fail to properly decode the data. I am only interested decompression in this case. It follows the standard pattern:

- Read Huffman values -> Like normal JPEG
- unzigzag -> Like normal JPEG
- Dequantize -> Like normal JPEG
- IDCT -> Almost like normal JPEG, but different range/clamping
- Color Space conversion -> Custom, not YCbCr

For one 8x8 except for the last step that looks like this right now:

```
int16_t processBlock(int16_t prevDc, BitStream &stream, const tHuffTable &dcTable, const tHuffTable &acTable,
                     float *quantTable, bool isLuminance, int16_t *outBlock) {
    int16_t workBlock[64] = {0};
    int16_t curDc = decodeBlock(stream, workBlock, dcTable, acTable, prevDc); 
    unzigzag(workBlock);
    dequantize(workBlock, quantTable);
    idct(outBlock, workBlock, isLuminance);
    return curDc;
}
```

after this the `outBlock` is treated by the color space conversion based on the image type.

What I want to optimize is the overall performance. The entire image is decompressed in the following way with 4 luminance blocks for component 1, 1 chrominance block for component 2 and 1 chrominance block for component 3. There are 4 more blocks for another luminance component, but I dont know what it is used for, so we can ignore it. The code looks like this:

```
void decodeImageType0(
        uint32_t width,
        uint32_t height,
        std::vector<uint8_t> &outData,
        BitStream &stream,
        const tHuffTable &dcLumTable,
        const tHuffTable &acLumTable,
        const tHuffTable &dcCromTable,
        const tHuffTable &acCromTable,
        float *lumQuant[4],
        float *cromQuant[4]) {
    int16_t lum0[4][64]{};
    int16_t lum1[4][64]{};
    int16_t crom0[64]{};
    int16_t crom1[64]{};
    uint32_t colorBlock[16 * 16]{};

    const auto actualHeight = ((height + 15) / 16) * 16;
    const auto actualWidth = ((width + 15) / 16) * 16;

    int16_t prevDc[4] = {0};
    for (auto y = 0; y < (actualHeight / 16); ++y) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < (actualWidth / 16); ++x) {
            for (auto &lum : lum0) {
                prevDc[0] = processBlock(prevDc[0], stream, dcLumTable, acLumTable, lumQuant[0], true, lum);
            }
            prevDc[1] = processBlock(prevDc[1], stream, dcCromTable, acCromTable, cromQuant[1], false, crom0);
            prevDc[2] = processBlock(prevDc[2], stream, dcCromTable, acCromTable, cromQuant[2], false, crom1);
            for (auto &lum : lum1) {
                prevDc[3] = processBlock(prevDc[3], stream, dcLumTable, acLumTable, lumQuant[3], true, lum);
            }

            decodeColorBlockType0(lum0, lum1, crom0, crom1, colorBlock);
            for (auto row = 0; row < 16; ++row) {
                if(y * 16 + row >= height || x * 16 >= width) {
                    continue;
                }

                const auto numPixels = std::min(16u, width - x * 16);
                memcpy(outData.data() + (y * 16 + row) * width * 4 + x * 16 * 4, &colorBlock[row * 16], numPixels * 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my measurements have shown that over 80% of the time is spent inside the `idct` function, so this is where I want to optimize. The function looks like this, after I applied what I could think of to optimize it. I have created a cache of the static coefficients used in the IDCT process which significantly improved performance, but I hope there is still room for more, for example nanojpg is 3 times faster (however with invalid results).

```
float idctHelper(const int16_t *inBlock, int32_t u, int32_t v, int32_t blockWidth, int32_t blockHeight) {
    glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp> vec3{};

    float result = 0.0f;
    for (auto y = 0; y < blockHeight; ++y) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < blockWidth; x += 4) {
            const auto idx = (v * 8 + u) * 64 + y * 8 + x;
            vec3 = glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp>(inBlock[y * blockWidth + x], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 1], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 2], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 3]) *
                    glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp>(idctLookup[idx], idctLookup[idx + 1], idctLookup[idx + 2], idctLookup[idx + 3]);
            result += vec3.x + vec3.y + vec3.z + vec3.w;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename T, typename U = T>
U clamp(T value, T min, T max) {
    return static_cast<U>(std::min<T>(std::max<T>(value, min), max));
}

void idct(int16_t *outBlock, int16_t *inBlock, bool isLuminance, int32_t blockWidth = 8, int32_t blockHeight = 8) {
    for (auto y = 0; y < blockHeight; ++y) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < blockWidth; ++x) {
            auto value = static_cast<int16_t>(std::round(
                    0.25f * idctHelper(inBlock, x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight)));
            if (isLuminance) {
                value = clamp<int16_t>(static_cast<int16_t>(value + 128), 0, 255);
            } else {
                value = clamp<int16_t>(value, -256, 255);
            }

            outBlock[y * blockWidth + x] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the cache that is created once at the start of the application outside of time measurements:

```
float alphaFunction(int32_t n) {
    static float INV_SQRT_2 = 1.0f / sqrtf(2.0f);

    if (n == 0) {
        return INV_SQRT_2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
        for (auto u = 0; u < 8; ++u) {
            for (auto v = 0; v < 8; ++v) {
                for (auto x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
                    for (auto y = 0; y < 8; ++y) {
                        idctLookup[(v * 8 + u) * 64 + y * 8 + x] = alphaFunction(x) * alphaFunction(y) *
                                                                   cosf((2 * u + 1) * x * (float) M_PI / 16.0f) *
                                                                   cosf((2 * v + 1) * y * (float) M_PI / 16.0f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code at the end with the four nested `for` loops — is that part of a function or what?

Comment: I have edited the question. It is created only once at the start of the application and is not part of the measured times.

Comment: Instead of `round(0.25f` etcetera use integer math (i.e. int division). Where feasible.

Answer (score 1):

DCT can be implemented with a fast algorithm. I understand you implemented it with a matrix multiplication, which is much less efficient.

DCT algorithms are similar to FFT ones. You can find many references with a simple search, on Wikipedia for example